# how to disable GPU's ULPS (Ultra-low power state) feature?

Tags: drivers, display, power-management, freeze, amdgpu

Since 2011, AMD has an ULPS (Ultra-low power state) feature in its GPUs also marketed as "AMD ZeroCore Power" technology.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#ZeroCore_Power

At least on Windows, ULPS malfunctions sometimes. Mostly, the screen stays black after some sort of energy-saving.

I have some recurring **problems** with

- the screen staying black after the display (was) turned off or went to standby,
- system freeze,
- soft-shutdown not working properly and
- application freeze while display is turned off

**affecting different Linux-based partitions on 2 PCs with different hardware**.

I would like to test disabling the ULPS feature. But I only know how to do it on Windows OSs. I could not find a way to deactivate it in Linux distributions - neither per online search nor on Linux-centric websites/communities. If someone knows how to disable (and re-enable) ULPS, please tell or share a link. Thank you very much!

Or please tell me where I should ask this question.

Sincerely

Fragmentraumer